# Changing window.location.href Aborts AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

I have an HTML page with a button. When the user clicks on the button, `window.location.href` is updated to the URL of a text file. The text file is served with `Content-Disposition: attachment`, so the file is downloaded & does not open in the browser.

The problem is that there are also AJAX requests occurring on this page. Whenever window.location.href is changed, all of the AJAX requests silently abort (or at the very least, the `jQuery.ajax error` event is not triggered).

**So how can I download a file without reloading the page or aborting any AJAX?** I need to do this in IE7+ (***Update:*** *Needs to work in IE7+ & modern browsers, including iOS & Android)*.

Here is some sample code. I created two endpoints in Express; `/ajax` just responds a simple JSON; `/download` responds with a text file after ten seconds. If you click on "Start AJAX" to request `/ajax` followed by "Start Download" to request `/download`, the AJAX request is aborted. The timer is just for ease-of-use.

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Firefox Download &amp; AJAX Test</title>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

<body>
<form method="GET" action="">
<button id="btn-ajax" type="submit">Start AJAX</button>
<button id="btn-download" type="submit">Start Download</button>
</form>

<div id="dynamic-content"></div>

<script>
(function() {
    var $dynamicContent = $("#dynamic-content");

    $("form").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

    $("#btn-ajax").click(function() {
        var $btn = $(this).prop("disabled", true),
                left = 10,
                countdown;

        function tick() {
            if ( left <= 0 ) {
                stop();
            }

            $dynamicContent.text(left--);
        }

        function stop() {
            $btn.prop("disabled", false);
            clearInterval(countdown);
        }

        countdown = setInterval(tick, 1000);
        tick();

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/ajax",
            complete: stop,

            success: function(data) {
                $dynamicContent.text(data.value);
            },

            error: function() {
                $dynamicContent.text("Error!");
            }
        });
    });

    $("#btn-download").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "/download";
    });
})();
</script>
```

**Express Router**

```
// GET /download
exports.download = function(req, res) {
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.txt");
    res.send("You have downloaded this text file");
};

// GET /ajax
exports.ajax = function(req, res) {
    setTimeout(function() { res.send({ value: "Success!" }); }, 10000);
};
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As you've set up the response headers to tell the browser it's a download, rather than pointing the current page to the link why not open a new window (which immediately vanishes as the browser sees such headers)

```
window.open('/download', '_blank');
```

---

A second way is to point to the location using an `<iframe>` that the user can't see

```html
<iframe id="downframe" src="about:blank" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

```js
document.getElementById('downframe').src = '/download';
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Unfortunately, i don't think i can use either of these solutions. 

1) window.open is something I have tried in the past.  Gets blocked by popup blockers too much. 
2) An <iframe> will not work because content-disposition: attachment is ignored in iOS, so the file does not "download" & would be trapped in the invisible <iframe>.

Comment: @Markus if it's a _HTML5_ browser, you might be able to simulate a click on an `<a href="link" download="filename"></a>`